# Jquery "Droppy" drop-down menu - not hiding properly on mouseout

Tags: jquery

I have a drop down menu that I am happy with, but... It does not properly hide the appropriate sub menus if you mouse out while a sub menu is active.

It will hide initially, but when you try to use the menu again, it is buggy. I know its because its not properly hiding in the first place. An idea I had was to 'reset' the menu every time it is initialized.

> http://jsfiddle.net/YmaAE/

I think it may have to do with the **hide** function which ive already messed around with a lot:

```
function hide() {
    var subnav = getSubnav(this);
    if (!subnav) return;
    $.data(subnav, 'cancelHide', false);
    setTimeout(function() {
        if (!$.data(subnav, 'cancelHide')) {
            $(subnav).hide("fast");
        }
    }, 500);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I usually like to help figure out what's wrong with code, but drop down menus are tricky.

I've used [DDSmoothMenu](http://www.dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex1/ddsmoothmenu.htm) a bunch of times and it's always worked well. CSS is easy to tweak for your styling needs, and it works well in all browsers.